# Why tkinter not working properly for python when file run with terminal in mac

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm using `tkinter` to build `gui` with my mac.normally I'm using python `IDLE` to run and test the code. I created a new file with `.py` extension and run it. it works properly. this is the code.

```
from tkinter import *

mywin  = Tk();
mywin.title("window for mac")
```

**This works fine**

Then I tried to run the file using `terminal` and tried to launch the file with python launcher.at that time it gives following error

```
  File "check.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tkinter import *
    ImportError: No module named tkinter
```

my python version is `Python 2.7.10`. some says it is corruption on python. I tried to install python with home-brew also.but didn't get any result.

Comment: Maybe `MAC` used python version `2.X` and idle run with `3.X`. Try on terminal `python3 blahblah.py`

Comment: what can I do to get both for same version

Comment: @dsgdfg I tried with your answer in the comment, it didn't give any error.code execute but didn't give the `window`

Comment: `No module named tkinter` is python2.X error ! `No module named Tkinter` is python3.X error. Are you sure ?

Comment: On terminal `can't display gui without any 'mainloop'` !

Comment: yep, I forgot it.now its working.put this as answer to accept and is there a way to get both terminal and idle versions to same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idle and Terminal python version are different !
Need using same version of Python.

No module named tkinter is python2.X error ! No module named Tkinter is python3.X error.